# Firebase уведомления

Tags: firebase, уведомления

можно ли отправлять уведомления, только когда приложение в фоне, и не активно

Comment: можно отправлять)

Comment: а как можно? )))

Comment: Так а что вы именно спрашиваете? Пользуясь сервисом Cloud Messaging Firebase можно отправлять push-уведомления на устройства, на которых установлено ваше приложение. Придет ли уведомление если приложение в фоне или не активно? да придет.

Comment: я делаю небольшой чат, мне надо чтобы сообщения приходили через Firebase, когда приложение в фоне, а когда активно через websocket и при этом чтоб не показывались уведомления.

Comment: Вероятно вам нужно добавить проверку на активность приложения вроде этого : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30937201/13941944

Comment: спасибо большое